# How to find similarities between a text string and an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, string, search

I have a string array, which I want to compare with a text string, if it finds similarities I want to be able to mark in black the similarity found within the string

example:

```
context.body: 'G-22-6-04136 - PatientName1'

newBody: ['G-22-6-04136 - PatientName1' , 'G-22-6-04137 - PatientName2']
```

When finding the similarity between the two the result would be something like this

```
newBody: [**'G-22-6-04136 - PatientName1'** , 'G-22-6-04137 - PatientName2']
```

How could I do it? Is this possible to do? In advance thank you very much for the help

```
const totalSize: number = this.getSizeFromAttachments(attachments);
const chunkSplit = Math.floor(isNaN(totalSize) ? 1 : totalSize / this.LIMIT_ATTACHMENTS) + 1; 
const attachmentsChunk: any[][] = _.chunk(attachments, chunkSplit);

if ((totalSize > this.LIMIT_ATTACHMENTS) && attachmentsChunk?.length >= 1) {
   
    const result = attachment.map(element => this.getCantidad.find(y => element.content === y.content))
            const aux = this.namePatient
            const ans = [] 
            result.forEach(ele => {
              const expected_key = ele["correlative_soli"];
              if (aux[expected_key]) {
                const newItem = { ...ele };
                newItem["name_Patient"] = aux[expected_key]
                newItem["fileName"] = `${expected_key}${aux[expected_key] ? ' - ' + aux[expected_key] : null}\n`.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
                ans.push(newItem)
              }
            });
            
            let newBody: any;
            const resultFilter = attachment.map(element => element.content);

            const newArr = [];
            ans.filter(element => {
              if (resultFilter.includes(element.content)) {
                newArr.push({
                  fileNameC: element.fileName
                })
              }
            })

            newBody = `• ${newArr.map(element => element.fileNameC)}`;

            const date = this.cleanDateSolic;
            const amoung= attachmentsChunk?.length;
            const getCurrent = `(${index}/${attachmentsChunk?.length})`
            const header = `${this.cleanDateSolic} pront ${attachmentsChunk?.length} mail. This is the (${index}/${attachmentsChunk?.length})`;

            console.log('body', context.body);
   
           // context.body is the body I receive of frontend like a string

            const newContext = {
              newDate: date,
              amoung: amoung,
              getCurrent: getCurrent,
              newBody: newBody,
              ...context
            }
 
            return this.prepareEmail({
              to: to,
              subject: ` ${subject} (Correo ${index}/${attachmentsChunk?.length})`,
              template: template,
              context: newContext,
            }, attachment);
 
}
```

Comment: Please rewrite the typescript in to plain JS and ise the `[<>]` snippet editor to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have a string array, which I want to compare with a text string, if it finds similarities I want to be able to mark in black the similarity found within the string*

First of all the text will be in black by default, I think you are talking about to make that bold if matched. But again it depends - If you want to render that in HTML then instead of `**` you can use `<strong>`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const textString = 'G-22-6-04136 - PatientName1';

let arr = ['G-22-6-04136 - PatientName1', 'G-22-6-04137 - PatientName2'];

const res = arr.map(str => str === textString ? `<strong>${str}<strong>` : str);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res[0];
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, it looks like the string needs to be an exact match, is that correct?

Also, *"mark it in bold"* is going to depend on what you're using to render this, but if you just want to wrap the string in `**` or `<b>` or whatever, you could do something like this:

```
newBody.map(str => str === context.body ? `**${str}**` : str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just see if string exists in the array by doing
`if arr.includes(desiredStr) //make text bold`